# Get reference to XAML element not from this class

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

To make a templemate that I will be inserting in my class a few times, I made a new XAML element:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.EntryPage_Field"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Name="GridItem" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="300" Height="400">
        <TextBlock Text="test"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Now I want to get the GridItem and place it in my class, but I can't get a reference to it.

```
            Grid el = (Grid)EntryPage_Field.FindName("GridItem");
            ViewGrid.Items.Add(el);
```

Doesnt compile at all.

```
            Grid el = (Grid)FindName("GridItem");
            ViewGrid.Items.Add(el);
```

Crashes as el is null.

Just to clarify, I want my templemate to be empty every time I use it, so maybe I should call new somewhere?

Comment: What's a "templemate", and what problem were you trying to solve by writing this code? This looks like an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that shouldn't be very difficult to resolve. As it is you seem to be trying to reinvent WPF's templating feature, which is a bad idea. Better, and much easier, just to properly use the feature they gave you.

Comment: If you add a bunch of these, they will all have the same name because it is hard coded, so you won't be able to pick a specific one by name.  You might want to look into implementing this as a UserControl instead of a Page and leaving the name blank.  You can assign a different name to each one as you add it to the parent, and that way, you can reference any one you want.

Comment: Why going into trouble with this: `Grid el = (Grid)EntryPage_Field.FindName("GridItem");`? Why don't you use `GridItem` variable directly?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I wanted to insert a structure (a Grid with an image and two text field) several (unknown) times into my ViewGrid, each time with different images and texts, but the layout would be the same.

Comment: @CodeSharpMarvin That's a start. What exactly defines the "items" you're adding into the ViewGrid? Some collection somewhere? Do you have a collection of items, and you want to display all of them in a list, using the same "cloned" UI fragment for each one? If that's the case you're in luck, WPF loves doing that stuff for you and I can show you how.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, It is an ImageView and two TextBlocks. They should be arranged in a certain way and I planned to do this with a Grid and I want to display these cloned items in a Grid. It would be great to hear how to do that, although I am coding for UWP.

Comment: I'm going to ask several questions. I will need complete and specific and concrete answers to every single one of those questions, and don't leave any out, because I'm a cranky old man who lives under a bridge and bites children's ankles when they speak in abstractions. 1. Do you have a viewmodel? 2. Where is the collection? 3. What are the properties of the class contained in the collection? 4. Please give me the XAML you would use to display one (1) of the items.

Comment: The XAML should go in your question, it'll be unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `GridItem` Grid from the page, you can use your `EntryPage_Field` **class object instance**.

Try the following code to get the `GridItem` from the `EntryPage_Field` class, then put it into `ViewGrid` Grid witch is in another page. Before you add the `GridItem` into `ViewGrid`, you should make sure the `GridItem` is not the child of other Control or page.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EntryPage_Field myPage = new EntryPage_Field();
    Grid myGrid = (Grid)myPage.FindName("GridItem");
    myPage.Content = null;
    ViewGrid.Children.Add(myGrid);
}
```